# HttpClient Get or Post doesn't work with .NETCore 2.1 and 2.2, but works with .NETCore 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I use Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.4, .NET Standard 2.0.3 and the last version of .NETCore 2.1.6. I run my application on Windows 10 64bits.

This code :

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://httpbin.org/")
                ...
```

doesn't work with the last version of .NET Core 2.1 or 2.2.
I have this exception :

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at EliorNugetCommon.Tests.APIManagerTests.Get() in D:\Git\Elior-Group\WebApiServices\NugetWAS\EliorNugetCommon\EliorNugetCommon.Tests\APIManagerTests.cs:line 50
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
Result Message: 
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
---- System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : A task was canceled.
```

But, that works with .NET Core 2.0.9 !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you making multiple calls?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Try making the Get call synchronous instead. (troubleshooting step only)

Comment: Only external calls fails. If .NET Core 2.1 and 2.2 doesn't use proxy, how to do now ?

Answer (score 1):

With the new HTTP stack in .NET Core and .NET Core 2.2, there is a regression with the authentification behind a proxy. In this case, we can use the .NET Core 2.0 HTTP stack this switch :

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

For more information, the discussion is here : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30166